# How do I save a cursor position?

Tags: cursor, session

How can  I save the cursor position for every file I have opened? So, next time I open the file, the cursor will be at the position I last opened it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`saveplace`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SavePlace) has you covered:

```
(require 'saveplace)
(setq-default save-place t)
```

Comment: For Emacs 25 and after: `(save-place-mode)`

Comment: Seems like this sometimes work, sometimes does no work when using `C-x C-c`

Answer (score 2):

Bookmarks can save your point position. I am currently getting a lot of mileage from bookmarks by using them instead of traditional desktop saving. This solution will provide many side benefits, as I shall describe below.

1. Edit a buffer and leave the point where you like.
2. Save as normal with C-x C-s.
3. Set a bookmark with C-x r m.
4. Close the buffer.
5. List bookmarks with C-x r l.
6. Move the point to the name of the file with C-s filename...
7. Press enter twice to load the file into a buffer.
8. Notice that the point is exactly where you left it; smile.

I like this workflow because:

- It gives me a permanent record of every file I ever edit.
- The buffer content is searchable, copyable, and accessible to macros and Lisp functions.
- Emacs remembers the location of the file; no more searching my hard drive for that little used shell script I wrote three years ago.
- The bookmark file loads very quickly, even if it grows very long, as compared to my old desktop with dozens of large files loading every time I run Emacs.
- Bookmarks has many more features I haven't even explored yet, like most of Emacs.

The one disadvantage to this workflow is that I must manually set the bookmark every time I save the file. The next step would be, I believe, to add a "hook" to automatically bookmark every file I save. I haven't gotten there yet, but I'm sure someone has that already figured out.

Comment: Bookmarks are complementary with saveplace. Saveplace does that automatic saving of the position. Bookmarks have their use too, but they aren't really adapted to what is requested in this question.